# Handle exceptions with coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand try catch mechanism on coroutine and curious about its behavior.

Here's piece of code showing

```
val job: Job = Job()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)
scope.funTryCatch()

fun CoroutineScope.funThrowException(): Deferred<String> = async {
    error("Throw exception")
}

fun CoroutineScope.funTryCatch() = launch {
    try {
        funThrowException().await()                               
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Exception: $e")
    }
}
```

What I expect is there in no crash happen in Application and console log prints "Throw exception" message,

but above code results in crash even console log prints "Throw exception" message.

I am confused with this behavior because the exception is caught, how can this exception crashes Application?

Does anyone could help me figure out this situation? Thanks!

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Thanks for replying, but my APP still crashes while executing it. Does there is any reason for this different behavior? As to custom exception handler, it can handled instead of exception propagation, but I real want to know is why exception still propagates even using try/catch block (Assume not using custom exception handler ).